# Source of the quote "I will blurb your book, or I will read it, but not both"

Tags: quotes, larry-niven

This is a quote I heard in the mid to late 1980's, attributed to a famous SF author (I usually think it's Larry Niven).

But the quote appears to have fallen into the dreaded Internet Late 1980s History Donut Hole.

I heard it either on a TV broadcast, or from the professor who was teaching our History of Science Fiction class.

Can anyone track down a real attribution for this quote?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This issue of *New York Magazine* from Feb. 6, 1989](https://books.google.com/books?id=qugCAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA47&dq=blurb%20book%20read%20%22not%20both%22&pg=PA47#v=onepage&q=blurb%20book%20read%20%22not%20both%22&f=false) attributes it not to a SF writer, but to mystery writer Robert B. Parker (and says it comes from the economist John Kenneth Galbraith, though I couldn't find anything to support that).

> As the mystery writer Robert B. Parker, quoting John Kenneth Galbraith, likes to say to novelists petitioning him for a line of praise, "I'll blurb your book or I'll read it, but not both."

Comment: Nice.  I bow to your google-fu. :)

Comment: So what would his blurbs consist of?  *"I loved every line I read"*, *"Worth every penny I paid for it"*, *"I couldn't put this book down"* (implied: because I never picked it up)